# What is the difference between by self and alone?

Tags: word-meaning, difference

I have seen  in a book

- was she with friends?
- no, she was by herself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this context, both mean the same thing (without companions) - but...

*He alone survived the accident* (he was the only survivor). You can't use *by himself* here.

*(To child) Did you draw that picture by yourself?* (without being helped). You can't use *alone* here.